# stored procedure to remove quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will removed leading and trailing quotes from an arbitrary table and column. I keep getting an error saying that the table name isn't declared.

Here is the SP

```
create table [dbo].[test] (id nvarchar(20))
insert into dbo.test values ('"07617966004766"')
go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_stripDoubleQuotes 
    @tableName sysname,
    @columnName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE @tableName
    SET @columnName = SUBSTRING(@columnName, 2, LEN(@columnName))
    WHERE LEFT(@columnName, 1) = '"'

    UPDATE @tableName
    SET @columnName = SUBSTRING(@columnName, 1, LEN(@columnName)-1)
    WHERE RIGHT(@columnName, 1) = '"'

END
GO
exec [dbo].[sp_stripDoubleQuotes] N'[dbo].[test]', N'[id]'



select * from test
```

Here is a link to a fiddle:
[link to fiddle](http://rextester.com/KVLE79144)

Comment: I do not think you could use parameter directly in the `SP`, try use dynamic sql

Comment: You can't do that, you would either need to use dynamic SQL, or come up with something that uses sys.tables and sys.columns for example?

Comment: You should avoid the sp_ prefix, or even better use no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Why do you need a procedure to do this kind of thing? Seems rather strange like there is a much bigger issue happening and this is dealing with the symptom instead of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_stripDoubleQuotes 
    @tableName sysname,
    @columnName sysname,
    @SQL varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    
    SET @SQL =

    'UPDATE ' + '[' + @tableName +']' +
    'SET' + '[' + @columnName +']' +'= SUBSTRING(' +'[' + @columnName +']' +', 2, LEN(' +'[' + @columnName +']' +'))
    WHERE LEFT('  + '[' + @columnName +']' +', 1) = '+'''"'''
    --PRINT(@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)

    SET @SQL =
    'UPDATE ' + '[' + @tableName +']' +
    'SET' + '[' + @columnName +']' +'= SUBSTRING(' + '[' + @columnName +']' +', 1, LEN(' + '[' + @columnName + ']' +')-1)
    WHERE RIGHT(' + '[' + @columnName +']' +', 1) = '+'''"'''
    --PRINT(@SQL)
    EXEC (@SQL)
END
GO
exec [dbo].[sp_stripDoubleQuotes] N'test', N'id'  -- exec [dbo].[sp_stripDoubleQuotes] N'[dbo].[test]', N'[id]'
```

Updated 2nd: I added `[]` to wrap table and column incase your table and column name have whitespace in them. Thanks @Sean Lange and @Richard

Updated 3rd: As @[benjamin moskovits] (xD) mentioned, if you hard coded brackets, the correct execute command is `exec [dbo].[sp_stripDoubleQuotes] N'test', N'id'`. Try to add or remove brackets and `print` to see whether the syntax is correct before executing it.

Comment: Try to comment out `EXEC` and comment in `PRINT` before it take into effect

Comment: You might also need some spaces in there, e.g. between 'UPDATE' and the table name, etc.

Comment: @RichardHansell thanks for correcting me, I am so careless :(

Comment: This won't work as posted. There are no spaces before or after the object names. You should also wrap those object names with QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection and deal with horrible names.

Comment: You still need more spaces. After the table name, after SET

Comment: This worked, for some reason it didn't work in the fiddle, but it worked in sql server.

Comment: quotename will probably add too many squarebraces. Try executing it with the print uncommented.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits what do you mean? If you don't use quotename and your table name is "Some Name" this will fail.

Comment: I see....now they added brackets. While this will work it is vulnerable to sql injection. This is why I would use quotename and take out the hard coded square brackets.

Comment: @SeanLange, yes, injection is a issue :(

Comment: @Long - if you use quotename instead of the hard coded brackets it will make this far less prone to injection.

Comment: @SeanLange, I see, for injection part, I need to read more, just have few concepts now, thank you ;)

Comment: when you pass in schema/table names already in square brackets you may have issues.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits well that would be poor development to try to pass in a table name like that. You would want to pass in the actual name of the table, not some additional stuff around it.

Comment: Look at the example spitfired posted.,... Anyway I don't want to continue this. For the example invocation the solution was valid. However it would be cleaner, and safer, to invoke as parameters which are then surrounded with quotename in the proc.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_stripDoubleQuotes 
    @tableName sysname,
    @columnName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @QuerytoExecute varchar(1000) 
    set @QuerytoExecute="UPDATE "+@tableName+"
    SET "+@columnName+" = SUBSTRING("+@columnName+", 2, LEN("+@columnName+"))
    WHERE LEFT("+@columnName+", 1) = '""'";
    exec (@QuerytoExecute);
    set @QuerytoExecute="
    UPDATE "+@tableName+"
    SET "+@columnName+" = SUBSTRING("+@columnName+", 1, LEN("+@columnName+")-1)
    WHERE RIGHT("+@columnName+", 1) = '""'";
    exec (@QuerytoExecute);
END
GO
```

Comment: This looks like a sloppy version of the same code that Long posted already.